# macoOS openclc crashes with Illegal instruction: 4 when trying to --migrate source code

Tags: xcode, macos, opencl

I have a working Hello World program, borrowed from these [two](https://jameshfisher.com/2017/04/19/macos-opencl-hello-world/) [sites](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/OpenCL_Hello_World_Example/Listings/hello_c.html).
I'm trying to migrate it to metal code using this command:

```bash
openclc --migrate hello.c
```

When I run that command, it crashes with Illegal Instruction 4:

```
0  libLLVMContainer.dylib   0x00007ffa3257fc95 PrintStackTrace(void*) + 37
1  libLLVMContainer.dylib   0x00007ffa325800bd SignalHandler(int) + 493
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ff81c9d9c1d _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 000000000000000000 _sigtramp + 18446603370100843520
4  openclc                  0x00000001029b246c cc1_main(char const**, char const**, char const*, void*) + 1564
5  openclc                  0x00000001029b4006 main + 1395
6  dyld                     0x00000002034a9310 start + 2432
Stack dump:
0.  Program arguments: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/openclc -cc1 -triple x86_64-apple-macosx10.18.0 -migrate -disable-free -disable-llvm-verifier -main-file-name ocl.c -pic-level 2 -mdisable-fp-elim -masm-verbose -munwind-tables -target-cpu core2 -target-linker-version 133.3 -resource-dir /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/../lib/clang/3.2 -fmodule-cache-path /var/folders/qy/3y6k069d0h58zd4wkb53ksnh0000gn/T/clang-module-cache -fdebug-compilation-dir /Users/risner/Documents/stackoverflow/winterbash -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 80 -stack-protector 1 -mstackrealign -fblocks -fobjc-runtime=macosx-10.18.0 -fobjc-dispatch-method=mixed -fobjc-default-synthesize-properties -fdiagnostics-show-option -fcolor-diagnostics -o ocl.remap -x c ocl.c
openclc: error: unable to execute command: Illegal instruction: 4
openclc: error: clang frontend command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
LLVM version 3.2
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
openclc: note: diagnostic msg: PLEASE submit a bug report to http://llvm.org/bugs/ and include the crash backtrace, preprocessed source, and associated run script.
openclc: note: diagnostic msg: Error generating preprocessed source(s).
```

I was expecting to see the OpenCL code migrated to Metal code using the `openclc` tool apple provides to convert OpenCL to native Metal graphics commands.

I should point out this tool is provided with the Operating System, I did not install `openclc`. It is in a private framework of the OS:

```
/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUCompiler.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/openclc
```

Xcode calls this tool automatically when compiling *OpenCL* code to compile to binary.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @willeke Trying to use the Apple supplied OpenCL converter software dev tool (openclc) to convert code from the deprecated OpenCL on macOS to metal.